# Отправка писем через мой сервер, используя python

Tags: python, linux, сервер, smtp, email

Имею только что настроенный iredmail email сервер (все настройки стандартные). Какие дополнительные настройки необходимо произвести, чтобы можно было отправлять письма через данный сервер используя python и его библиотеку smtp?

На данный момент получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Error:  SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

**python Код:**

```
import smtplib
import email.utils
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

HOST = "**********"
PORT = 25

BODY_HTML = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
  <p>This email was sent via my script</p>
</body>
</html>
            """

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Тестовое письмо"
msg['From'] = "****"
msg['To'] = "*******"
part1 = MIMEText("", 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(BODY_HTML, 'html')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST, PORT)
    server.connect(HOST, 25)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("****************", "******")
    server.sendmail("******", "*******", msg.as_string())
    server.close()
except Exception as e:
    print ("Error: ", e)
else:
    print ("Email sent!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Нужно было сменить 25 порт на 587.